# Kernel execution time drops when not initializing buffers

Tags: performance, opencl, intel

I am experiencing strange behaviour when measuring the execution time of an OpenCL kernel. The kernel expects three buffers as input. I create those buffers in the host code and initialize them by using CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR. I then measure the kernel execution time via OpenCL events. However, when I omit CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, the kernel execution time drops to a third.

So far I discovered that this problem has something to do with optimizations done by the OpenCL compiler. It looks like the compiler notices that the buffers are not getting initialized and optimizes the kernel accordingly. If I supply the flag "-cl-opt-disable" there is no difference in execution time between initializing and not initializing the buffers. But disabling all optimizations is obviously not what I intend to do.

Is there a way to stop the compiler from noticing that the buffers have not been initialized without disabling all optimizations? Writing just one byte into the buffer didn't do the trick unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using clenqueuewrite or clenqueuemap ? Maybe you are doing an extra copy with these?

Comment: So you're trying to microbenchmark something, and want the compiler not to optimize the kernel differently?  So you can test it without the potential bottleneck of actually copying memory from the host to the GPU?  Are you sure that's not already what's happening?  i.e. maybe it's faster because the memory is just staying cached on the GPU?  (That might not make sense, I don't really know OpenCL, mostly just optimization and how hardware works in general).

Answer (score 1):

`CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` forces the CL driver to perform a copy of your memory to the Device. Therefore any further kernel execution that depends on that data for reading will be blocked until the copy operation finishes.

Kernel execution times (as reported by CL profiling) will surely be the same in both cases. However, if you are just measuring from CPU side (please, never do that!) you will see the execution time increase, even though the kernel is not really running, but waiting to a copy operation.

By disabling optimizations, the kernel time may have bigger impact than the copy, are therefore shadowing it in the measurement.

*NOTE: Some more things you may try.*

- Set your kernel to "write_only" or your CL buffer to "WRITE_ONLY", that should make the kernel run instantly even if the buffer is not ready.
- Put a sleep() after the buffer creation
- Run the kernel 2 times and measure the second one.